# preg_match_all confusing failing

Tags: php, preg-match-all

```
$string = (string) file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

echo $string;

// Correctly echos string contents

preg_match_all("/[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+@[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+/i", $string, $matches);

print_r($matches);

// No matches
```

I am parsing text/csv files and grabbing email addresses from uploaded files. When parsing a Google Contact file I exported it weirdly fails. But when I simply copy the string that is echo'd and paste that instead of the file_get_contents result, it parses and works.

Any idea why it is refusing to take the `file_get_contents` string, but if I paste in the raw data myself, it works?

Comment: I think it's the `file_get_contents` and uploading problem, you should remove the `preg-match-all` tag?
EDIT: try using `move_uploaded_file` then read it?

Comment: Just a note; Since you're using the case-insensitive modifier, I believe it's redundant including both cases of alpha character ranges in your character classes. `a-z` should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

`$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` is a temporary uploaded file, you should move to a directory first before calling `file_get_contents`, like

```
$tmp_file = '/tmp/test.csv'
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $tmp_file);
$string = file_get_contents($tmp_file);
```

Comment: what did not solved? had you tried to `var_dump($string);` and `var_dump($_FILES);`?

Comment: There may be errors. Turn error displaying on (in `php.ini`) if you're using a development environment, or write errors to a log file (again change `php.ini`) and see.

Comment: Upon checking with var_dump of the string, it is actually corrupted encoding that seems to be the problem. If I echo the string, it works ok, but var_dump creates a mess. "string '��N�a�m�e�,�G�" for example. mb_detect_encoding simply returns false whenever I try to detect the encoding. Any ideas?